# My FlutterBarcodeScanner is outputing a `-1` when I press the cancel button in the scan screen

Tags: flutter, dart

whenever I press the cancel button in the barcode/QR code scan screen, I get a `-1` result on the output alert dialog. How do I Catch the number and replace it with a Text that makes sense to a user?

The Barcode/Qr Code Function

```
 Future <void> scanqr() async {
      final qrCode = await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode(
          "#ff6666", "Cancel", true, ScanMode.QR);

      setState(() {
        this.qrCode = qrCode;
      });

      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) => _buildPopupDialog(context));

  }
```

The Alert Dialog Widget

```
 Widget _buildPopupDialog(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
        buttonPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        scrollable: true,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
        title: Text(
          "You Scanned the Following Product:",
          style: TextStyle(),
        ),
        content: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              qrCode,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: scanqr,
            child: Text(
              "Re-Scan",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.amber),
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home_page()),
            ),
            child: Text(
              "Home",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.amber),
            ),
          )
        ]);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

at 8 month ago of the question, I have a solution, inside of Future function I handled like this:

```
 if (barcodeScanRes != "-1") {
      setState(() {
        _scanBarcode = barcodeScanRes;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _scanBarcode = "Scan canceled";
      });
    }
```